# Отправим [denwer] поездом в [Денвер]!

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

Синонимизировать [denwer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denwer) и [денвер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80). На [официальном сайте](http://www.denwer.ru/) употребляются оба варианта. Вроде бы больше «Денверов», относящихся к тематике Stack Overflow, нет.

Comment: Not enough pun! )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, отправим [denwer] поездом в [Денвер].

Comment: Думаю, апдейт надо сделать ответом, чтобы за него можно было голосовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, сделано! [*(Капчу пришлось проходить)*](https://i.gyazo.com/10d4e8dbc1df2a1a11c2e2cab298119f.png).

Comment: Хм.. Без картинки и без иконки отсутствующей картинки - странно. У меня в ней [по-прежнему не хватает картинки](/q/1757/178988).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*Перенесено из вопроса*

Раз [зашёл вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3025/199934), какую метку сделать основной, склоняюсь к варианту [денвер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80). Согласно тому же официальному сайту название сборки — акроним от «Джентльменский набор Web-разработчика», на английском бы вышло что-то вроде «Gentlman's set of Web developer». Для разработчиков родной язык русский, «Denwer» — производное от «Денвер» (если быть точным, «Д.н.w.р»), а не наоборот.

Comment: Скажите, а на каком основании вы приняли этот ответ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin наверно потому что он свой? и более устраивает

Comment: Для справки: в момент принятия на обоих ответах было по 3 голоса, т.е. поровну.

Answer (score 6):

В случае, когда метка — название продукта, всегда используется непереведенный вариант. Поэтому основной - [denwer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denwer), синоним - [денвер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80)

В данный момент статистика использования явно говорит в пользу [denwer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denwer):

- [denwer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denwer) 103 раза
- [денвер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80) 3 раза

Метка [denwer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denwer) также имеет краткое описание, [созданное Etki ещё в апреле 2015 года](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/419777/revisions):

> Denwer (Джентельменский Набор Веб-разработчика) - это одна из первых сборок программ (Apache, MySQL, PHP) необходимых для создания базового окружения разработки веб-программиста.

---

Предложил синоним, можно проголосовать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/denwer/synonyms

---

18 июня: подтвердил синоним.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос аргументом об основном названии метки.