# Сообщение о вводе капчи

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[Здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3024/199934) перенёс текст из вопроса в ответ. мне было предложено ввести капчу.

[image: Капча]

Фраза «Проверьте поле с кодом CAPTCHA», вероятно, архаизм со времён, когда пользователям требовалось вводить текст, а не выбирать картинки. И даже тогда корректнее звучало бы что-то вроде «Введите код CAPTCHA», а не «проверьте».

Также не стоит запятая, разделяющая части сложного предложения: « (... ) точно определить, человек Вы или робот.» Можно и «счет» заменить на «счёт».

Comment: "Проверьте" - это кривой перевод англ. "check", в отношении флажка (checkbox), который надо включить.